# Loading an Excel Validation list directly from a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, validation

I want to know if it's possible to load an Excel Validation list directly from an external query. I'm expecting to do this in VBA somehow. I have the query which works fine and I can load the resultant list into a table in a worksheet via VBA without a problem, but I wanted to know if I can use this result set directly into a validation list without having to first load the query results into a workbook and then refer to this table as the source for the validation list.

I'm working with MySQL and Excel 2016 and the combination works well for everything so far, but I'm stuck on this. Any ideas please?

Comment: Like a worksheet change event that checks a cell entry against an array holding your query recordset? Thinking out loud and haven't tried to see if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and it is easy if you use Excel tables.

You need to always save the records returned from your SQL query into an Excel table. You can create it each time or you can just create one, rename it and always keep it there in a visible or hidden worksheet. It depends on you.

Let's say that you have created an Excel Table that keeps the options for your drop down list and it is called `Table1`. The trick is when you are defining the validation in the cell (or cells), in the `Source` section you write this:

```
=INDIRECT("Table1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I know I can save the results into a table, my question was how to use the results from the query without saving them into a table first.

Comment: It depends on the size of the records. You cannot insert more than 255 characters in the `Source` section so if you are sure your records altogether character count will be less than 255 characters, then you can simply insert them as `option1,option2,option3,...`. If the character count exceeds 255 then your options will be truncated, but will not fail

Comment: BTW, by `saving` I did not mean that you have to really save the workbook if you simply dump the results there and once you are done, close your workbook and not save it, it is all fine, your drop-down will work just fine. In this case, I would rather remove the validation before closing the workbook since if your options change constantly, then they would show validation errors when you use the workbook later

Comment: Thanks lbo - unfortunately my list is very much bigger than this, approx. 400 rows with up to 60 chars per entry.

Comment: There is no other way and that is how Excel works, you have only 2 options: 1-direct entry (limited to 255 characters) 2-Excel range (range must be consecutive and not scattered) I have worked on this for a very long time in a big data governance project and I am sure so you have to go with the range option

Comment: you did not give me enough details, but practically you need to dump your records once in a sheet and take care of filtration for each drop down in Excel with VBA/Excel itself. Many connections to DB may fail or hinder users from having a good performance

Comment: Thanks all - I guess I'll just go with loading the results into a table on a hidden tab and validating against that if that's the best Excel can offer. Thanks for your input everyone.

Comment: You can upvite people or choose the right answer for your questions so helpers can get credit for that :)